# Removing every instance of the empty list from a list of list

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I'm new to Haskell and am just trying to write a simple list comprehension to remove every instance of the empty list from a list of lists, i.e entering this..

```
> remove ["abfwfw", "wfgwg", "", "dfw"]
```

will result in this output...

```
> ["abfwfw", "wfgwg", "dfw"]
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 22):

[Filter](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v:filter) is your friend.

```
filter (not . null) ...
```

alternatively, for those who like to filter manually,

```
[ x | x <- xs , not (null x) ]
```

Answer (score 13):

`Filter` would probably help you.

```
> filter (not . null) ["abfwfw", "wfgwg", "", "dfw"] 
["abfwfw","wfgwg","dfw"]
```

What we are doing here is checking every element of a list whether its length equal to null or not with a predicate function `(not . null) :: [a] -> Bool`.

There is a nice [explanation](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#maps-and-filters) of what filters are and how they work.